# add multiple products in the invoice throught multiple clicks and quantity is decreases when we add a new product in the present invoice document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

By one click the loop is executed 23 times.
Here the schema of product api and invoice api

//product api schema

const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({

name:{
type:String,
required:true,
},

Category:{
type:String,
required:true
},

Quantity:Number,

Price:Number

})

const userdb=new mongoose.model("userData",userSchema)

module.exports=userdb

//invoice api schema

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

invoiceNumber: String,

date:String,

customerName: String,

product: {
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'userdb'
},

Quantity: Number,

total:Number,

price:Number,

items:Array

})

const invoicedb=new mongoose.model("invoiceData",invoiceSchema)

module.exports=invoicedb

const Product = require("../schema/usersch")

const Invoice = require("../schema/invoicesch");

exports.create = async (req, res) => {

try {

const products = req.body.product;

const invoiceItems = [];

```
// Loop through each product and add it to the invoice items array
for (const productData in products) {
  const product = await Product.findById(products);
  if (!product) {
    // Handle the case where no product was found with the given ID
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `Product with ID ${productData.id} not found` });
  }
     
  if (product.Quantity < req.body.Quantity) {
    // Handle the case where there is not enough quantity to fulfill the sale
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `Not enough quantity available for product with ID ${productData.id}` });
  }
  

  const total = req.body.Quantity * product.Price;
  product.Quantity -= req.body.Quantity;

  const invoiceItem = {
    product: product._id,
    Quantity: req.body.Quantity,
    total: total,
    price: product.Price
  };

  invoiceItems.push(invoiceItem);

  await product.save();
// res.status(201).json(product);

}

// Create a new invoice document with the invoice data and save it to the database
const newInvoice = new Invoice({
  date: req.body.date,
  customerName: req.body.customerName,
  invoiceNumber: req.body.invoiceNumber,
  items: invoiceItems
});

const info = await newInvoice.save();

// Return the new invoice document
```

res.status(201).json(newInvoice);

} catch (err) {

console.error(err);

```
res.status(400).json({ error:'Server error'});
```

}
}